# Is this matrix positive semidefinite? $M_{ij} = \sqrt{|x_i+x_j|} - \sqrt{|x_i-x_j|}$ where $x_i$'s are reals

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, positive-semidefinite

Let finite number of $x_i$'s be reals. Define matrix $M_{ij} = \sqrt{|x_i+x_j|} - \sqrt{|x_i-x_j|}$. Is this matrix positive semidefinite?

I am reading this year's IMO problem number 2, which would be trivially true if we prove that $M_{ij}$ is positive semidefinite.

> **Problem $\boldsymbol2$.** Show that the inequality
> $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sqrt{\left|x_i - x_j\right|} \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\sqrt{\left|x_i + x_j\right|}$$
> holds for all real numbers $x_1,...,x_n$.

Comment: After trying a few random examples in MATLAB, it appears that $M$ is in fact PSD, although I suspect proving it will be harder than solving the IMO problem. I wonder if the techniques in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3954342/155509) are useful here.

Comment: See: #58 in https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6t243f6h2625850_mount_inequality_erupts_downwards

Comment: A matrix is positive semidefinite iff all principal minors are nonnegative (according to this paper: http://prussing.ae.illinois.edu/semidef.pdf). It would be enough to prove that $det(M) \geq 0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define $f(x, y) = \sqrt{|x + y|} - \sqrt{|x-y|}$. Then we want to prove that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[f(X, Y)] \ge 0
\end{align*}
where $X, Y$ independent and uniformly distributed over the set of values $\{x_1, \cdots, x_n\}$.

[**Remark 1**: I know the IMO is motivated to use techniques only available at the secondary school level, but the probabilistic notation allows me to naturally represent a bunch of summation notations in a succinct form, and can be translated easily to the summation notation in the original problem.]

First, let's observe the region in the Cartesian plane where $f(x, y) \ge a$ and $f(x, y) \le -a$, respectively:

[image]

And therefore
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(f(X, Y) \ge a) &= \mathbb{P}\left(X \ge \frac{a}{2}, Y \ge \frac{a}{2}\right) + \mathbb{P}\left(X \le -\frac{a}{2}, Y \le -\frac{a}{2}\right) \\
&= \mathbb{P}\left(X \ge \frac{a}{2}\right)^2 + \mathbb{P}\left(X \le -\frac{a}{2}\right)^2
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(f(X, Y) \le a) &= \mathbb{P}\left(X \ge \frac{a}{2}, Y \le -\frac{a}{2}\right) + \mathbb{P}\left(X \le -\frac{a}{2}, Y \ge \frac{a}{2}\right) \\
&= 2\mathbb{P}\left(X \ge \frac{a}{2}\right) \left(X \le -\frac{a}{2}\right)
\end{align*}
Then, we need the lemma that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[A] = \int_0^\infty [\mathbb{P}(A \ge a) - \mathbb{P}(A \le -a)]da
\end{align*}

which can be proved by noticing that $\mathbb{E}[A] = \mathbb{E}[A^+] - \mathbb{E}[A^-]$, where $A^+ = \max(A, 0)$ and $A^- = -\min(A, 0)$ and then applying the proof for the [tail sum formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63756/tail-sum-for-expectation). Letting $A = f(X, Y)$,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[f(X, Y)] &= \int_0^\infty[\mathbb{P}(f(X, Y) \ge a) - \mathbb{P}(f(X, Y) \le -a)]da \\
&= \int_0^\infty\left[\mathbb{P}\left(X \ge \frac{a}{2}\right) - \mathbb{P}\left(X \le -\frac{a}{2}\right)\right]^2da \\
&\ge 0
\end{align*}

**Remark 2**: Note this proof works for any $f(x, y) = g(|x+y|) - g(|x - y|)$ for non-decreasing $g: \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and general distributions for $X, Y$. For example, we also have the result
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i,j} w_i w_j \log(1 + |x_i - x_j|) \le \sum_{i,j} w_i w_j \log(1 + |x_i + x_j|)
\end{align*}
for weights $w_1, \cdots, w_n \ge 0$.

**Remark 3**: Completely forgot to answer the original problem. Note that if we choose $g(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and define $X, Y$ to be random variables distributed over $x_1, \cdots, x_n$ with weights $w_1, \cdots, w_n \ge 0$, then we effectively get, for $\mathbf{M} = [M_{ij}]_{ij}$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{w}^\intercal \mathbf{M}\mathbf{w} \ge 0
\end{align*}
for $\mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^n_{\ge 0}$; we need $\mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ in order to get genuine positive semidefiniteness. But it appears that if we replace $\mathbb{P}$ with [quasiprobability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiprobability_distribution) distribution (e.g. negative measures are allowed), everything in the proof still seems to go through.

Comment: See my Remark 3. I believe everything still works with the final tweeking.